# Getting arguments of S3 method in R

Tags: r, function, arguments

I get see the argument of any `R` function with `args` function, like

```
args(cor)
function (x, y = NULL, use = "everything", method = c("pearson", 
    "kendall", "spearman")) 
NULL
```

However, not able to see the arguments of cor.test. See this example:

```
args(cor.test)
function (x, ...) 
NULL
```

**Edited**

However the arguments of `cor.test` are

```
cor.test(x, ...)

## Default S3 method:
cor.test(x, y,
         alternative = c("two.sided", "less", "greater"),
         method = c("pearson", "kendall", "spearman"),
         exact = NULL, conf.level = 0.95, continuity = FALSE, ...)

## S3 method for class 'formula'
cor.test(formula, data, subset, na.action, ...)
```

I want to extract

```
cor.test(x, y,
         alternative = c("two.sided", "less", "greater"),
         method = c("pearson", "kendall", "spearman"),
         exact = NULL, conf.level = 0.95, continuity = FALSE, ...)
```

Comment: `x` and `...` are the correct arguments to `cor.test`. the `...` allows anything to be passed as an argument. You can see the function's documentation here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.4.1/topics/cor.test

Comment: If you want the arguments of the method instead of the generic you need args(cor.test.default).

Comment: On `R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)` `args(cor.test.default)` gives **Error in args(cor.test.default) : object 'cor.test.default' not found**.

Comment: The problem is that on `R version 3.4`, `cor.test.default` is not exported by package `stats`, so you may use `stats:::` to access it like `args(stats:::cor.test.default)`.

Comment: Thanks @Consistency for useful comment. Would appreciate if you change your comment to answer for future users. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. Answer added and you can also use `argsAnywhere(cor.test.default)` to get argument for internal S3 methods in packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `R version 3.4`, although `cor.test` is exported by package `stats`, S3 methods like `cor.test.default` and `cor.test.formula` is not exported, so you need to use `stats:::` to access them and then you can use `arg` to get their arguments like `args(stats:::cor.test.default)`.

Or you can use `argsAnywhere` to get arguments for functions and methods no matter where it is like `argsAnywhere(cor.test.default)`.